# Definition and properties of tangent functional

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, measure-theory, banach-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

I am reading *Measures Which Agree on Balls* by Hoffmann-Jørgensen and I am somewhat confused. Here, $E$ is a Banach space, $S$ is the unit sphere, and $x \in S$.

> We let $\tau(x, \cdot)$ denote the tangent functional at $x$, that is,
> $$ \tau(x, y)=\lim _{t \rightarrow 0+} t^{-1}(\|x+t y\|-1), \quad
>  \forall y \in E . $$
>
> It is well known [reference] that $\tau(x, \cdot)$ is subadditive,
> positively homogeneous, and that $$ \tau(x, y)=\sup _{x^* \in
>  T(x)}\left\langle x^*, y\right\rangle, \quad \forall x \in S, \quad
> \forall y \in E, $$

where $T(x)=\{ x^* \in E^* : \|x^*\| \leq 1, \langle x^*, x \rangle =1 \}$.

There is a reference made to V.9 of *Linear Operators* by Dunford, but the tangent functional is defined differently there and even then I see no proof that
$$
\tau(x, y)=\sup _{x^* \in T(x)}\left\langle x^*, y\right\rangle, \quad \forall x \in S, \quad \forall y \in E.
$$
Can anyone provide a proof of this contention with the provided definition or a reference to one? Also, if anyone has any informal explanation of the tangent functional, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any $x\in S$ and $y\in E$. We have to show that
\begin{equation*}
\tau(x,y)\overset{\text{(?)}}=\rho(x,y):=\sup_{f\in T(x)}f(y). \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
Generalize the definition of $T(\cdot)$ as follows: for any $z\in E$, let
\begin{equation*}
    T(z):=\{f\in E^*\colon\|f\|\le1,\ f(z)=\|z\|\}; 
\end{equation*}
then $T(z)\ne\emptyset$, by the Hahn--Banach theorem.

For any $f\in T(x)$ and any real $t>0$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    \|x+ty\|\ge\sup_{f\in T(x)}f(x+ty)=\sup_{f\in T(x)}(1+tf(y))=1+t\rho(x,y), 
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
    \tau(x,y)=\lim_{t\downarrow0}\frac{\|x+ty\|-1}t\ge\rho(x,y). \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}

For each real $t>0$, take any $f_t\in T(x+ty)$. By the [Banach–Alaoglu theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Banach-AlaogluTheorem.html), there is a subnet $(f_s)$ of the net $(f_t)_{t>0}$ converging in  the weak-* topology to some $f\in E^*$ with $\|f\|\le1$, so that $f_s(x)\to f(x)$ and $f_s(y)\to f(y)$.

So,
\begin{equation}
    -\infty<-\|y\|\le\frac{\|x+sy\|-1}s=\frac{f_s(x+sy)-1}s \\ 
    =\frac{f_s(x)-1}s+f_s(y)=:g_s(x,y). \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation}
Note that $f(x)\le\|f\|\,\|x\|=\|f\|\le1$. So, if $f(x)\ne1$, then $f(x)<1$ and hence $g_s(x,y)\to\lim_s\frac{f(x)-1}s+f(y)=-\infty$, which contradicts \eqref{3}. It follows that $f(x)=1$, so that $f\in T(x)$ and
\begin{equation}
\tau(x,y)=\lim_s\frac{\|x+sy\|-1}s= f(y)\le\rho(x,y), \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation}
by the definition of $\rho(x,y)$ in \eqref{1}.

Now (the first equality in) \eqref{1} follows immediately from \eqref{2} and \eqref{4}. $\quad\Box$

Comment: Why is the limit in (3) justified? It seems like we need to take s to 0 everywhere s appears, not first for f_s.

Comment: @ilikemath : I have rewritten this sentence. Hopefully, it is clear and clean now -- please let me know.

Comment: @ilikemath : Do you have a further response to my answer and comment?

Comment: No, it's great. Marked as accepted.

Comment: I think there is a small error here. Clearly, $T(x)$ is only nonempty when $\|x\|>1$, so we can not necessarily take $f_t$ from $T(x+ty)$. Instead, we need to take $f_t$ from $T(\frac{x+ty}{\|x+ty\|})$. Then, everything past this still works by homogeneity.

Comment: @ilikemath : Thank you for your comment. This is now fixed, by generalizing the definition of $T(\cdot)$.